# Minor Upgrade requirements

Tags: wix, upgrade

I wanna use minor upgrades, but I have two questions about the requirements for this type of upgrade.

Is it possible:

1. to remove a file(not KeyPath) from a component which is shared just in one existing feature  (and after the removing the component is still not empty)?
2. to remove an existing component (I guess that it will violate the rules)?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> to remove a file(not KeyPath) from a component which is shared just in
>   one existing feature

You can remove it from your upgraded package, but the update won't remove it on the target machine. A component is updated only if it's key path is changed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368599(v=vs.85).aspx

To remove it you can try using a custom action, but I'm not sure it will work. The best approach for removing resources when updating is using a major upgrade.

> to remove an existing component (I guess that it will violate the
>   rules)?

If you remove a component it's no longer a minor upgrade. This falls into the major upgrade category.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, but it is not recommended. [Changing the Component Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367849) documents that addition or removal of files requires changing the component code. If you do not, [What happens if the component rules are broken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372795) describes some of what can go wrong. Note that minor upgrades are often particularly picky about component rules.

Removing a component across a minor upgrade is also a no-no. Instead [some people recommend](http://geekswithblogs.net/Vagmi.Mudumbai/archive/2006/06/11/81426.aspx) marking that component as transitive and giving it a false condition to have it be removed during the minor upgrade. Note that component rules still apply to the component that only exists to be removed.